# Xcode build problems, many undefined symbol

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

[image]

I don't see these error when I am in the unity project, those undefined symbol is working fine in my IDE. And I managed to build it as an Xcode project, however, when I build from x code it has these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the solution, you need to enable cocoapods inorder to use google cloud anchor